# Is this Palm Tree in danger of falling?

Tags: trees

Is this Palm Tree in danger of falling?

[image: Palm leaning]

Comment: It depends, how long has it been on a lean?

Comment: Tree has been leaning for about 2 to 3 years.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if it might at some point because of all the flaking and cracking on one side at the base - it suggests something is going on towards the base of the trunk. If you are able to, go out and give it a hard push or three in the direction it's leaning, that is, push from the side on the right of the photograph. If it's close to falling, it should move when you do this, or it will be stable and solid and not move at all. Just make sure no one is on the wrong side of the tree when you do this in case it does fall and causes harm or damage. If it is solid and immovable, repeat the push test periodically as time goes by, if its easily movable, have it removed before it does fall. Palms may be related to grasses and bamboos, but the trunk falling onto someone is likely to cause injury.

Answer (score 1):

Palm tress grow at all sorts of angles in the wild.  Since it has been like that for a few years, it will probably be okay.  But keep a lookout for **Exposed Roots** and the following -

[What Causes a Palm Tree to Fall?](https://www.weekand.com/home-garden/article/causes-palm-tree-fall-18056345.php)

> 1. Wind
> 2. Sudden Crown Drop
> 3. Borers
> 4. Planting Depth

Another one with similar points
[Why is My Palm Tree Falling Over?](https://ecofamilylife.com/garden/why-is-my-palm-tree-falling-over/)

> 1. Strong Winds
> 2. Not Enough Water
> 3. Poor Root Growth
> 4. Sudden Crown Drop
> 5. Insect Damage
> 6. Shallow Planting Depth
> 7. Lightning and Storms
> 8. Flooding
>
> **Signs of a Dying Palm Tree**
> A dying palm tree is characterized by wilting, sagging, or discolored leaves. Two of the most common diseases are bacterial bud rot and lethal yellowing disease.
>
> If the leaves are white or yellow in color, you might need a copper fungicide. In addition, if you do not see any green leaves whatsoever, the tree is likely either dying or already dead.

Answer (score 0):

Palm tree's aren't conventional trees, they are more closely related to grass or bamboo. Hence a thick root crown is not a visible indicator the tree will collapse. Many palm trees tilt. Often grow in direction of ideal sun or wind swept.

In any case there seems be a lot of lichen/moss growing on one side likely indicative of necrosis of the root flesh. Holes in the trunk (smooth skinned) these are all signs of a palm dying or sick. If you can best to dispose and start new palm. If you think you can save it.

- Fertilize slow release citrus fertilizer or one meant for palm with an NPK ratio of 3-1-3 but has lots of micronutrient selenium, copper, Boron, Copper, Iron.
- Water more periodically.
- Spray off moss/lichen
- check parasites/pests